# Different attack types (labels) in training set than in test set

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, dataset, classification, intrusion-detection

I am currently working on KDD CUP 99 and NSL-KDD datasets (Intrusion detection datasets). They are divided into training and test sets, however when I go through the sets they have different attack types (data labels).

Is it normal?

The accuracy of predictions on the test set will be decreased because of the classes which my classifier was not be able to classify correctly since it was never trained on them.

Thank you!

Comment: The classes must remain the same across training and testing datasets.

Comment: Then how am I suppose to proceed when the official datasets are not having the same classes?